# Unable to delete Azure Storage Account With Versioning Enabled

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Hi have only one Storage account in my subscription with versioning enabled and now i wanted to delete that but unable to do so.

[image]

while trying to delete this, it's throwing error, I can not change the settings, i have tried to delete the resource group as well but no luck.

[image]

Another error message i am getting,

[image]

Storage account having the below container:
[image]

While trying to open any of these it's showing,

[image]

I am unable to delete any containers as well,

[image]

there is nothing in access policy for the container either,
[image]

Comment: I was able to delete an empty storage account with `Enable version-level immutability support` on. Do you have any containers under this storage account?

Comment: yes, i have updated the question.

Comment: See @Gaurav Mantri's answer.

Comment: add role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" then try to switch account to azure AD

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with versioning. If you see the error message in the 2nd screenshot, your storage account is protected by a `WORM` policy.

In all likelihood, a blob container in your storage account has `version-level immutability enabled` which is preventing that storage account from being deleted.

To delete the storage account, you would first need to find that container and disable the version level immutability (or simply delete the container). After that you should be able to delete the account.

You may find this link helpful to learn more about the data protection options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-protection-overview#overview-of-data-protection-options.

To clear the legal hold on a container, please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/immutable-policy-configure-container-scope?tabs=azure-portal#configure-or-clear-a-legal-hold.

Comment: where can i find "the version level immutability" for any container? i can't see any options, i am new in azure.

Comment: Please delete all containers first and then you should be able to delete the account.

Comment: I can not delete the containers as it says, "Failed to delete 1 out of 1 container(s):
insights-metrics-pt1m: ContainerProtectedFromDeletion: The storage account demo01applicationlogs container insights-metrics-pt1m is protected from deletion due to ImmutableStorageWithVersioning."

Comment: Can you try the instructions in the 2nd link in my answer?

Comment: there is nothing in the access policy section for the container, added the screen shot in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you check the deleted version and click on version tab, you will be able to delete the version and the entry will go away. No need to turn on "version-level immutability support"

Answer (score 0):

To be able to delete the Storage account. The container needs to be empty of any files. These files needs be deleted and the option selected to delete the file, the Also delete snapshots tick-box needs to be enabled. After the files have been deleted the container needs to be deleted and then the Storage account can be successfully deleted. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, The Networking configuration was set to **Disabled**, I just changed the configuration to **Enabled from all networks** , and then I was able to delete the container

Path to networking configuration: **Networking** => **Firewall and Virtual Networks** => **Public network access**

[image: azure]